# Where JanusGraph configuration is written?

Tags: janusgraph

I am reading the configuration reference for the JanusGraph https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.0/config-ref.html and I wonder - in which file should I write those values? Under conf directory of the JanusGraph there is no single common file in which I can write those options. I am so confused and documentation does not specify it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These configuration options should be put into a `.properties` configuration file. The JanusGraph distribution zip archive already contains example configuration files for different backends that can be used as a basis, for example for Cassandra with Elasticsearch: `conf/janusgraph-cql-es.properties`.

How these configuration files are provided to JanusGraph depends on whether you want to use JanusGraph embedded or via JanusGraph Server (which is the recommended approach). If you want to use JanusGraph Server, then you need a section that specifies this configuration file for JanusGraph in the configuration file of the server which is `conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml` by default:

```
graphs: {
  graph: conf/janusgraph-cql-es.properties
}
```

The chapter [*Using Configuration* of the JanusGraph docs](https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.3.1/configuration.html#_using_configuration) contains more information about how the configuration can be applied.

Comment: As far as I understand, then I am not required to use GremlinServer (all should be fine with Gremlin Server, because You mentioned where the configuration should be provided, thanks), I can use just Gremlin console to connect to the Cassandra directly and Gremlin console already knows how to process the CQL commands (there is no need for server, to process them). My problem is, that I can not reach "gremlin>" commandline, upon execution of gremlin.bat, this script complains about HADOOP_HOME (and gremlin.bat code shows that there is no other branch in this script without HADOOP_HOME).

Comment: So, I can not reach "gremlin>" prompt to write 'graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('path/to/configuration.properties')'.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different issue and I think that the comment section here is not very well suited to discuss that. I wanted to suggest that you create a dedicated question here for that or ask on [janusgraph-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/janusgraph-users) but it looks like you already did both.

Comment: I just thought that maybe gremlin console has its own configuration file apart from server, but apparently it doesnt. Its fine to use server as well, in any case I would have to server in future anyway.